# kotlin mockk test the length of time a delay has been called for

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, delay, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

I want to test that a delay() has been called for x amount of days in a coroutine. And i'm unsure how the following test works...

```
@Test
fun 'wait 5 days'() {

    ...

    runBlocking {
        service.main(testEnv)
    }

    val slot = slot<Long>()
    coVerify(exactly = 1) { testEnv.timeoutProvider.sleep(capture(slot)) }
    assert(slot.captured == 5.days.inMilliseconds.toLong())
}
```

`testEnv` is an object that contains a `timeoutProvider`. This `timeoutProvider` is used by the service to call a delay. I then want to verify that the delay that has been called is 5 days. Why does this test work?

```
open class TimeOutProvider {

    suspend fun sleep(timeInSeconds: Long) {
        delay(timeInSeconds * 1000L)
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask what the useCase is? Do you really wanna suspend the Coroutine for 5 days? Did you consider using WorkManager for delayed operations?

Comment: "Why does this test work?" Is this a typo or is it working and you wanna know why?